# Convert your AES_key, on a string

Tags: c, openssl

I would like to know how to convert the C type "AES_KEY" supplied with the openssl library into a string of characters to display, and then send it to a client.

Comment: I'm assuming the "bookseller" is an incorrect translation. The word you want is "library"

Comment: It is simple. Look at the type definition here: https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/2704/include/openssl/aes.h